# the alert is open before that the getPosition function is over

Tags: javascript, position

The getPosition() is a function that allows us to find our position, the problem is the alert came before the end of the function, at the fist time the alert is null and then I can get the values

```
 <input type="button" value="test" onClick="test()">
 <script>
 var coordinates = {latitude: null, longitude: null, error: false}
    
      function test(){
           getPosition();
           alert(coordinates.latitude);
      }

      function getPosition() {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
           function success (pos) {
                coordinates.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                coordinates.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
           }
           function fail(error){
                coordinates.error = true;
           }
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make the **alert** wait for the response from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

To do this, you can either use async/await as follows:

```js
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="test()">
<script>
 var coordinates = {latitude: null, longitude: null, error: false}
    
      async function test(){
           try {
            const result = await getPosition();
            alert(coordinates.latitude);
           } catch(error) {
                alert("Error getting coordinates");
           }
           
      }

      async function getPosition() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
           function success (pos) {
                coordinates.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                coordinates.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                resolve();
           }
           function fail(error){
                coordinates.error = true;
                reject(error);
           }
      });

      }
 </script>
```

or continue using callbacks as follows:

```js
 <input type="button" value="test" onClick="test()">
 <script>
 var coordinates = {latitude: null, longitude: null, error: false}
    
      function test(){
           getPosition();
      }

      function getPosition() {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
           function success (pos) {
                coordinates.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                coordinates.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                alert(coordinates.latitude);
           }
           function fail(error){
                coordinates.error = true;
                alert("Error getting coordinates");
           }
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a `coordinates` variable in the global scope? If not, one choice is to avoid initializing the `coordinates` variable outside the `getPosition` function. This way, the alert will *have* to happen after the user gives permission to get their location. For instance you could do the following:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="getPosition()">
<script>
      function getPosition() {
          var coordinates = {}
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
          
          function success (pos) {
            coordinates.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
            coordinates.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
            alert(coordinates.latitude)
          }
          function fail(error){
              coordinates.error = true;
          }
      }
</script>
```

You could simplify this approach even further by not setting a coordinates variable at all.

```
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="getPosition()">
<script>
      function getPosition() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
          
          function success (pos) {
            alert(pos.coords.longitude)
          }
          function fail(error){
            coordinates.error = true;
          }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because JavaScript is an asynchronous language (`alert()` fires before the `success()` function does), so I would recommend using **Promises** and **async/await** like so:

```html
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="test()">
<script>
    var coordinates = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        error: false
    }

    async function test() {
        try {
            //await will make code wait until resolve() is called
            await getPosition();
            //If this runs resolve() has ben called
        } catch(e) {
            //This means reject() has ben called
            //Therefore coordinates.error in no longeer needed
        }
        alert(coordinates.latitude);
    }

    function getPosition() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, reject);

            //Since you dont use any data in fail() i've replaced it with reject
            function success(pos) {
                coordinates.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                coordinates.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```